# GridView TextField validation still allowing next action despite errors

Tags: asp.net, validation, gridview

I have a GridView which has a TextField column in it .. I've setup validation for this TextField column so that it requires an input (i.e. its not optional), and that the input can be a positive integer only ..

The errors do show up when a text field is either empty or has doesn't have a positive integer value, but there's a server-side button which still executes even when there are errors in the GridView ..

I want the button to NOT do its processing if there are inputs errors .. Currently this doesn't happen, as the button's click event is still called even when there are errors ..

GridView Markup Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="EPSAndTSRValuesInputGridView" runat="server" ShowFooter="true"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EPS Value">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="EPSValue" Text='<%# Eval("EPSValue") %>' runat="server" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="Display"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid value for EPS!"
                        ValidationExpression="^\d*$" ControlToValidate="EPSValue" ValidationGroup="Display"/>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
                        ControlToValidate="EPSValue" ValidationGroup="Display"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Button which performs the next action:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDisplayReport2" 
    runat="server" CssClass="ButtonStyle" 
    Text="Display Report" ValidationGroup="Display" OnClick="btnDisplayReport2_Click" CausesValidation="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your Button have validation group `Display` so on click of it will validate only control  with same group i.e. `Display`.As I can see  there no validation group of your `Textbox` so it will not validate it in button click..,to cause validation on Click of Button Add same validation group in your `Textbox`,`RegularExpressionValidator`, and `RequiredFieldValidator`  too.

Comment: I have added them all to the same ValidationGroup now .. Still no change in behavior .. I have updated the main code above too ..

Comment: @Ahmad i still can not see the validation group of your textbox...add validation group in your textbox too....to make it work....

Comment: @Ahmad there is no other reason your code didn't work now...i tried it to it work for me,,

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because they don't have the same ValidationGroup.
Try adding  `ValidationGroup="Display"` to your validators.

Comment: Try to add the `ValidationGroup="Display"` on EPSValue also if you haven't yet.

Comment: you mean the textfield itself ?

Answer (score 0):

You are saying to execute the validation group Display on your button click.It will validate only control have the validation group (dispaly) as you mentioned.You are not defined any validation group for Textbox  validators Try by Add same validation group(displa) in your Textbox,**RegularExpressionValidator**, and **RequiredFieldValidator**.

Comment: It was a typo in my original code that I didn't mention `ValidationGroup="Display"` for the two validators .. This has been corrected now (see new code above) .. To summarize, I have added both the validators, and the button, to the same validation group now, and it doesn't doesn't stop button's click event to stop when there are input errors ..